# pre-populating a form field after choosing between many options using a radio button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, field

I have searched across the entire web and I cant seem to find a solution. I am pretty much searching a database for individuals. I can use last name for instance and then if two people have the same last name they both will print on my page. I want to be able to select the individual I would want ( or am for instance ) and click next ( a hyperlink to a page with blank forms ) which is where I would like the info of the individual I selected ( and what was printed on the page ) in the forms pre filled. It allows a more user friendly approach then having to re type the data and also avoid miss spelling of company name or drivers license for example. I have put my code up many times but here it is again.this is the code for the finding and printing of the search results. no radio button yet, as i am trying to figure that out.

```
<div id="results" style="width:750px;height:225px; text-align: center">

<?php

$host = "localhost"; //server
$db = ""; //database name
$user = ""; //databases user name
$pwd = ""; //password
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error()); 

$searchTerm = trim($_GET['searchname']);

// Check if $searchTerm is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
{
echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
exit();
} 

else 
{
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME,' ',    
  ARRIVAL) like '%$searchTerm%' GROUP BY FIRSTNAME";
$sql= "SELECT  * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL)   
 like '%$searchTerm%'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
//array_unique($count);
    if(($count)>=1)
    {
    $output = "";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

    $output .= "First Name: " . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "<br />";
    $output .= "Last Name: " . $row['LASTNAME'] . "<br />";
    $output .= "Arrival: " . $row['ARRIVAL'] . "<br />";    
    }
    echo $output; 
    //echo array_unique($output);
    }
    else
    echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
}
?>

</div>
```

this is the code for my form field which of course is a empty form that is just being submitted to the database after submission.

```
 <form action="insert_submit.php" method="post" style="margin-left:35px;">

First Name: <input type = "text" name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME" />


Last Name: <input type = "text" name="LASTNAME" id="LASTNAME"/>


Purpose: <input type = "text" name="PURPOSE" id="PURPOSE"/>


<br>
</br>
Company: <input type = "text" name="COMPANY" id="COMPANY" />


DL #: <input type = "text" name="DRIVERL" id="DRIVERL" />



 <br>
</br>

    <input type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Checked In">Log In
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Checked Out">Log Out
    <br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >

<br>
</br>

</form>
```

Comment: code vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: if your database has unique ids, then have your form send the unique id from the initial/selection page to the form page, and do another db lookup for the specific id selected... unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: so dave, how would i go about using the unique id because each input in the database does have the special id. I understand as far as the look up I am jsut not sure on how to use the printed id for the case we want and how exactly to take it to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so your output line would be something like (clean up to suit your formatting)

```
$output .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?userid='.$row['UNIQUEID'].'">
      First Name: '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'<br />
      Last Name: '.$row['LASTNAME'].'<br />
      Arrival: '.$row['ARRIVAL'].</a><br />';
```

and you build into the page a condition that if you have the UNIQUEID coming in to look up and fill out the form such as

```
Company: <input type = "text" name="COMPANY" id="COMPANY" value="<?PHP echo $row['COMPANY']; ?>" />
```

edit to suit your database of course

sample code formatting

```
if(something){
    do something
}else{
   while(){
   } # end while
}  # easy to see this matches the if/else set of brackets
```

**additional information for prepopulating**

easiest would probably be on the same page.  look for the userid coming into the page

```
if(!isset($_GET['userid'])){ 
     # meaning we do not have a userid from a url that we generated above
     # insert all your code to generate the links
}else{
     # meaning we *have* a userid from a url that we generated above

     # do your database query based on the userid such as
   $sql='select * from mytable where userid=?';
   $result=sqlsrv_query($db,$sql,array($_GET['userid']),array('Scrollable'=>'static'));
     # or use mysqli, pdo or whatever...  just watch for sql injection
   $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
     # assuming we will not have more than one element returned
   ?>
   First Name: <input type = "text" name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME" value="<?PHP echo $row['firstName']; ?>"/>

    and so forth...  that should get you started
```

Comment: im so close! thanks. im getting a odd error though: else 
 {$sql= "SELECT  * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL, ' ', ID) like '%$searchTerm%'";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
 if(($count)>=1)
 {
 $output = "";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {$output .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['localhost'].'?userid='.$row['id'].'">
      First Name: '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'<br />
      Last Name: '.$row['LASTNAME'].'<br />
      Arrival: '.$row['ARRIVAL'].'</a>' 
  }
 echo $output; }
 else
 echo " no matching record for the " . $searchTerm;
 }

Comment: format your code to indent your sections or brackets for easier reading and matching.  example above

Comment: missing a bracket after your "else"  `echo $output; } else echo " no matching record for the "`

Comment: after clicking on the hyper link, where do i signify the directing to the form page?

Comment: i got the hyper links to print properly though. thanks for that. my last step is to click on the appropriate one and have it progress to redirectcontractorpage.php and fill the form. almost done! well i hope

Comment: I see that the url changes based on the user id but im lost with redirecting and pulling the info based on the userid in the url also. sorry for the long need of help

Comment: see the edited addendum...  you can do on the same page, or split the two pages, the code will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you need is in the first page a lis of identical names, or ideally one name, like:

content, content, content,

FirstName, LastName
FirstName, LastName

And than if you click on either of them, than the user is redirected to another page, containing all the details of the selected person, in a form. If I am getting you right.

1. I would not use checkbos on the first page, simply make the person's name a hyperlink like:
   http://domain.com/userdetails?userid=666

So you pass on the user id to the second page. The php code on the second page can thank draw user details from the database and populate the form.

For that purpose you can either generate the form in an echo line-by-line manner, or use DomDocument tofind and fill the relevant value fields.

Second page form generation:
you select the row with the id, than fetch it into an array, named $array.

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query); //this query selected the row for the user with the id

echo '<form method="POST">'."\n";
echo '<input name="firstname" type="text" value="'.$array['firstname'].'">'."\n";
echo '<input name="lastname" type="text" value="'.$array['lastname'].'">'."\n";
echo '</form>';
```

I hope you get the idea now.

Comment: so your suggesting keeping a hyperlink on each users name and redirect to the next page to then do a lookup. is this hyperlink the only method?

Comment: so dave, this would be the similar code on the second page where i would have to go back in the db and get the info based on the hyperlink which was selected ?

Comment: yes.  page one, just handle your search and selection in case of multiple matches, showing the links.  Page 2, look up the uniqueid from page 1, and fill in the form with your db results for that uniqueid.

Comment: may i possibly have some guidance on how to begin the coding process. sorry i am really trying to figure this out as I have been stuck for a week now :( i do understand what needs to be done though. thanks for that